# Cannot get value for projected field

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, people-picker

We are calling expand on a people picker column of a custom list but get the following error due to a particular SharePoint user having a null value for EMail.

> Cannot get value for projected field Designee_x005f_EMail

The REST call is
`_api/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?&$select=Id,Title,Designee/Id,Designee/Title,Designee/EMail&$expand=Designee`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `$filter=Email gt ''`?

Comment: Yes, but the Designee/EMail portion of the select still causes it to fail. Not only that, but we don't want to filter out the users that do not have an Email; we still want to include the user as part of the search result.

Comment: Danny, Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, this was long enough ago that I can't really help out, I'm sorry. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

According to this Microsoft Support Post [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1667656c-0f44-41c7-a2e5-aa26e5937fb6/rest-api-sharepoint-2013-expand-does-not-work-when-user-assigned-to-has-multi-value?forum=sharepointcustomization), it won't work unless you have a value specified for referenced item field added as lookup column item.

On the post you can read:

> Please make sure the users you typed in BTApprover1 column have the FirstName. If not, the API REST will go wrong. If you aren’t sure if they have FirstName property, you can use Name property to test.